# How to generate UL Li list from string array using jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors, javascript-framework

I have string array like

> 'United States', 'Canada', 'Argentina', 'Armenia', 'Aruba',
>   'Australia', 'Austria', 'Azerbaijan', 'Bahamas', 'Bangladesh',
>   'Belarus', 'Belgium'**, ... etc.

I want create a dynamic list from string array like below:-

```
<ul class="mylist" style="z-index: 1; top: 474px; left: 228px; display: none; width: 324px;" > 
  <li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem">
     <a class="ui-all" tabindex="-1">
         United States
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem">
     <a class="ui-all" tabindex="-1">
         Canada
    </a>
  </li>
  <li> .... </li>
   .....
</ul>
```

How is it possible using jQuery?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

```
var countries = ['United States', 'Canada', 'Argentina', 'Armenia'];
var cList = $('ul.mylist')
$.each(countries, function(i)
{
    var li = $('<li/>')
        .addClass('ui-menu-item')
        .attr('role', 'menuitem')
        .appendTo(cList);
    var aaa = $('<a/>')
        .addClass('ui-all')
        .text(countries[i])
        .appendTo(li);
});
```

Comment: What the difference here to using vanilla js's .forEach() ?

Answer (score 20):

With ES6 you can write this:

```
const countries = ['United States', 'Canada', 'Argentina', 'Armenia'];

const $ul = $('<ul>', { class: "mylist" }).append(
  countries.map(country => 
    $("<li>").append($("<a>").text(country))
  )
);
```

Comment: you suggest also works. thanks for result in short line.
how can add new class "mylist" to UL list

Answer (score 14):

An even better approach using the array's **join** method

```
const countries = ['United States', 'Canada', 'Argentina', 'Armenia'];
const list = '<ul class="myList"><li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem"><a class="ui-all" tabindex="-1">' + countries.join('</a></li><li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem"><a class="ui-all" tabindex="-1">') + '</a></li></ul>';
```

Comment: if by better you mean shorter, then yes better. but not as simple to comprehend.

Comment: The opening `<a>` and closing `</a>` tags are unmatched. You need an opening `<a ...>` in the `join()` parameter.

Answer (score 6):

```
var countries = ['United States', 'Canada', 'Argentina', 'Armenia'];
var cList = $('ul.mylist')
$.each(countries, function(i) {
    var li = $('<li/>')
        .addClass('ui-menu-item')
        .attr('role', 'menuitem')
        .appendTo(cList);
    var a = $('<a/>')
        .addClass('ui-all')
        .text( this )
        .appendTo(li);
});
```

Comment: Thanks , I getting error message a is undefined in jquery javascript, I am using jquery 1.5.1. How to fixed it?

Comment: Switch over to the development version of jQuery. That'll show you where it's failing.

Answer (score 4):

```
    <script type="text/javascript" >
        function aa()
        {
            var YourArray = ['United States', 'Canada', 'Argentina', 'Armenia'];
            var ObjUl = $('<ul></ul>');
            for (i = 0; i < YourArray.length; i++)
            {
                var Objli = $('<li></li>');
                var Obja = $('<a></a>');

                ObjUl.addClass("ui-menu-item");
                ObjUl.attr("role", "menuitem");

                Obja.addClass("ui-all");
                Obja.attr("tabindex", "-1");

                Obja.text(YourArray[i]);
                Objli.append(Obja);

                ObjUl.append(Objli);
            }
            $('.DivSai').append(ObjUl);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="aa()">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="DivSai" >

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Other variation of [`Abhishek Bhalani`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/568085/abhishek-bhalani): You can use Array.map() instead of $.each()

```
var items = ['United States', 'Canada', 'Argentina', 'Armenia'];
var cList = $('ul.mylist');
items.map( (item,i ) => {
      var li = $('<li/>')
        .addClass('ui-menu-item')
        .attr('role', 'menuitem')
        .appendTo(cList);
      $('<a class="ui-all">'+ i + ': ' + item.name + '<a/>')
        .appendTo(li);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible without jQuery too! :)

```js
let countries = ['United States', 'Canada', 'Argentina', 'Armenia', 'Aruba'];

// The <ul> that we will add <li> elements to:
let myList = document.querySelector('ul.mylist');

// Loop over the Array of country names:
countries.forEach(function(value, index, array) {
  // Create an <li> element:
  let li = document.createElement('li');

  // Give it the desired classes & attributes:
  li.classList.add('ui-menu-item');
  li.setAttribute('role', 'menuitem');

  // Now create an <a> element:
  let a = document.createElement('a');

  // Give it the desired classes & attributes:
  a.classList.add('ui-all');
  a.tabIndex = -1;
  a.innerText = value; //  <--- the country name from our Array
  a.href = "#"

  // Now add the <a> to the <li>, and add the <li> to the <ul>
  li.appendChild(a);
  myList.appendChild(li);
});
```

```html
<ul class="mylist"></ul>
```