# How to deserialize nested sortable jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, nested-sortable

I use the `toArray` function to get the list using this line of code.

```
var sortedPage = $('ol.sortable').nestedSortable('toArray');
```

How can I reconstruct the list using this array?

Comment: What are you trying to do? It's not clear...

Comment: i used the above code to get the list into an array how to reverse the operation by using this array to build the nested sortable using this array !!!

Comment: Is this the same thing you are asking? [how-to-generate-ul-li-list-from-string-array-using-jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881033/how-to-generate-ul-li-list-from-string-array-using-jquery)

Comment: @joe thanks but not it's not the same thing this one is for the sorted not the nestedsortable

Comment: have you solved the question @Oddadmix?

Comment: Adding some context... the above question refers to a plugin that serializes a nested HTML list (typically an OL/UL). However, the author of the plugin has not implemented a method to deserialize and rebuild the nested list. Here's the plugin: https://github.com/ilikenwf/nestedSortable/blob/master/README.md