# display nested arrays as individual <ul> tags

Tags: jquery, multidimensional-array

I'm in the process of building a mega menu. Therefore if the list items are greater than 3, they should break in to new unordered lists. I am able to display them in an array which includes nested arrays. ex:- {{1,2,3}{4,5,6}{7,8,9}{10}}

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var postsArr = new Array(), 
$postsList = $('ul.posts');

$postsList.find('li').each(function(){
    postsArr.push($(this).html());

})

var arrays = [], size = 3;
while (postsArr.length > 0)
    arrays.push(postsArr.splice(0, size));

    console.log(arrays);

});
```

How can I print them as unordered lists, each containing 3 list items?

This is my fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/TqPkZ/

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you set a fiddle with an example? Makes it easier to help.

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/21141049/3639582

Comment: I just added my fiddle to make it more clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/TqPkZ/2/

I have put the check for the "threes" into the first loop and skipped the second one.

```
var postsArr = [], 
    $postsList = $('ul.posts'),
    size = 3;

    postsArr.push($(document.createElement('ul')));
    $postsList.find('li').each(function(i, e){     //i=current index iteration, e=the element itself    
        if((i+1) % size == 0) {
            postsArr.push($(document.createElement('ul')));
        }
        postsArr[ Math.floor(i/size) ].append(e);

    })

$("div").html(postsArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this:

```
var postsArr = new Array(),
    $postsList = $('ul.posts');

$postsList.find('li').each(function () {
    postsArr.push(this); //<----push the dom node instead

})


var arrays = [],
    size = 3;

while (postsArr.length > 0)
arrays.push(postsArr.splice(0, size));


//console.log(arrays);

$.each(arrays, function (i, item) { // loop in the arrays
    var ull = $('<ul/>'); // create a dynamic ul
    $.each(item, function (i, it) { // loop in the inner array object
        ull.append(it).appendTo('body'); // create ul for each array object
        console.log(i, ":::", it);
    });
});
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TqPkZ/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use this to wrap groups of three with a `<ul>` element:

```
$('.posts > li:nth-child(3n-2)').html(function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    return $('<ul>') // create <ul>
      .append($this.clone()) // append self
      .append($this.nextAll(':lt(2)')); // append up to two siblings
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/TqPkZ/3/)